# Ссылка на внешний <router-outlet> из внутреннего компонента. Angular 7

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-routing

Вот вроде задача простая. Прочитал достаточно ссылок но все равно не могу достичь нужного результата. Есть Главный компонент `<mat-sidenav-container>`. У него мы знаем есть боковая панель `<mat-sidenav>` и основное тело просмотра `<mat-sidenav-content>`.

Вот и в

```
<mat-sidenav-content class="body-sidenav">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Я вставлю аутлет. Тут все норм. Боковая панель отлично навигирует по этому аутлету и переходит между вкладками сайта.

Но у меня на одном компоненте, что рендериться в аутлете что я выше написал так же есть переход на детали продукта.

Во первых роутиг.

```
{
    path: 'article-section',
    component: AllSectionComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'article-section/:id',
        component: ArticleComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
```

Первая ссылка эта та что идет с боковой панели и открывает мне  список всех объектов. Ну и соответсвенно на каждом объекте в цикле ngFor я рендерю список со ссылкой у каждого на дочерний компонент(детали продукта)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of articleSection"
      style="width: 100px; margin-right:10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
      <img class="img-section" src="assets/images/docimgaes/section.png" /> 
      <br>
      <a [routerLink]="['/article-section', 1]">
        <div class="name-section">{{item.name}}</div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Но у меня только меняется строка в браузере и ошибки лезут в консоли. Пишут всюду что нужно еще один аутлет поставить на дочерний компонент article-section. Ведь основной то аутлет принадлежит `<mat-sidenav-content>`. Других пока нету. Ну вот я решил поставить еще один аутлет на страницу article-section и оно то работает. Но оно ж явно на html странице и теперь вместе самим объектами отображается детали продукта. Не лепить же костыли и вручную скрывать список объектов.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="center-folder">
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of articleSection"
      style="width: 100px; margin-right:10px; margin-left: 10px; margin- 
      bottom: 10px;">
      <img class="img-section" src="assets/images/docimgaes/section.png" /> 
        <br>
      <a [routerLink]="['/article-section', 1]">
        <div class="name-section">{{item.name}}</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно что б аутлет работал на уровень выше, тот что с боковой панели переводит. Как такое организовать???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все что нужно было это поменять систему маршрутизации роутеров и вынести компонет из дочернего на соседний.

```
       {
      path: 'article-section',
       component: AllSectionComponent,
       children: [
            {
          path: 'article-section/:id',
          component: ArticleComponent,
        },
       ]
```

И сделать вот так

```
       {
        path: 'article-section',
        component: AllSectionComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'article-section/:id',
        component: ArticleComponent,
      },
```